# C - I/O - Array of chars to print out sentence structure

Tags: c, arrays, io, char

So I am taking in a text file like so:

```
Hello. This is my test! I need to print sentences.
Can I do it? Any help is welcomed. Thanks!
```

And I am trying for output:

```
1. Hello.
2. This is my test!
3. I need to print sentences.
4. Can I do it?
...and so on....
```

Here is what I have written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
  main() {
     int storage[50];
     int i = 0 ;
     int linecount = 1 ;
     char c;

     for (;;) {
      c=getchar();
      if(c == '\n'){
        c == '\0';}
      storage[i] = c;
      i++;

      if (c == '.' || c == '!' || c == '?') {
        int j ;
        printf("%d. ", linecount++);
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
         printf("%c", storage[j]); }
        i = 0 ;
        printf("\n");
      }
   }
 }
```

And it results with output:

```
1. Hello.
2.  This is my test!
3.  I need to print sentences.
4. 
Can I do it?
5.  Any help is welcomed.
6.  Thanks!
```

My first issue is that it prints a '\n' for line 4, I thought that my code:

```
if(c == '\n'){
  c == '\0';}
```

Would take care of this, but that is not the case.

My second issue is that it adds an extra space char after the first record.
I know this is because I use the print statement:

```
"%d. "
```

and also the beginning of the sentences have a space to separate from last sentence but I am unsure on how to fix this issue. Any help would be great! Thanks! -qorz

Comment: Duplicate of [this SO question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354843/c-reading-and-identifying-sentences/22355557)

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue occurs because you need to use `=` operator, not `==`. You are actually testing the value instead of changing the array position to `\0`.

To fix this, change

```
if(c == '\n'){
    c == '\0';
}
```

to

```
if(c == '\n'){
    c = '\0';
}
```

For your second question, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122616/how-do-i-trim-leading-trailing-whitespace-in-a-standard-way).

Answer (score 0):

Here `==` is not assignment operator, change it to `=`

```
if(c == '\n'){
   c = '\0'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    int storage[50];
    int i = 0 ;
    int linecount = 1 ;
    int c;

    while(EOF!=(c=getchar())) {
        storage[i++] = c;
        if (c == '.' || c == '!' || c == '?') {
            int j ;
            printf("%d. ", linecount++);
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                printf("%c", storage[j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            i = 0 ;
            while(isspace(c=getchar()))
                ;//skip white spaces
            ungetc(c, stdin);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```